# JavascriptExecutor is not identifying the button to click in Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, browser-automation

I have this HTML

```
<div class="btnContr">    
  <input type="button" onclick="return cancel();" value="Cancel"/>
```

Below is the xpath identified, using this xpath, I am not able to click on the button.

```
Xpath=//div[@class='btnContr']/input[@onclick='return cancel();']
```

Code written:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)ff;
            jse.executeScript("document.getElement(By.xpath('//div[@class='btnContr']/input[@onclick='return cancel();']').click()");
```

What should my code be?

Comment: Is this the only Input tag inside that Div or does it contain other Input elements too?

Comment: Similar to Anuragh27's question- Are you sure the "btnContr" class name is unique?

Comment: Cannot it be done simpler, without JavaScript? E.g., `driver.findElement(By.css("input[value='Cancel']")).click()`

Comment: there is no method like `document.getElement()`. It is `document.getElementById()`. For finding element by xpath using javascriptexecutor you have to use `WebElement element=(WebElement)jse.executeScript("document.evaluate('xpath here')")`. Check the syntax of evaluate. It also takes some more arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your use of quotes - they don't match correctly. Since you're using three levels of quotes (around document.getElement; around the xpath; and for the attributes) you'll need to escape one pair.

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElement(By.xpath(\"//div[@class='btnContr']/input[@onclick='return cancel();']\").click()");
```

Comment: Tried your sollution. But still getting NullPointer Exception. It is as below java.lang.NullPointerException at com.lmm.ExcelLibrary.readExcelValue(ExcelLibrary.java:35) at com.lmm.Executor.testExecute(Executor.java:104) at OnFirefoxBrowser.LISTING_CANCEL.LISTING_CANCEL(LISTING_CANCEL.java:18) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: This looks like a completely different problem, as NPE is thrown by ExcelLibrary,not WebDriver nor your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver; //instantiated somewhere else, obviously
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='btnContr']/input[@value='Cancel']");
element.click();
```

Why are you bothering with JavascriptExecutor, when Selenium has the functionality to click an element selected by XPath built in?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use below format to avoid quotes errors:

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='btnContr']/input[@value='Cancel']"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to click and send text by using xpath in JSE. Here is how I've done it:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']"));
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Gmail']"));
String hi = "Hi";

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);  //for clicking

// for Entering text
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+hi+"';", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
WebElement elmnt =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signOutLink']"));   
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elmnt);
```

Comment: Is this meant to answer the question?

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or is it just a thank you comment?

Comment: This answer looks like a just copy paste of the above answer which was earlier answered by @Shubham Jain.

If you have resolved your issue, just accept the answer rather than the new answer.

Comment: The important part (the xpath) is different in this than in the other answer. Even if it was inspired by that answer as a jumping off point, it looks like the key part is different. I would contend (all else being equal) that this is an honest attempt at an answer.